# https is not working on httpd docker container

Tags: apache, docker, dockerfile, httpd.conf

I am new to Apache and docker. I am running httpd:2.4 image from docker hub. Httpd container is running fine. When I am hitting localhost from browser, it gives messages as "**IT workes**" but when i tried to hit localhost with https then it is giving error as site can not be reached.

command to run httpd

docker run -d -p 443:443 --name httpd httpd:2.4

Answer (score 2):

You must configure ssl certificate for this. Please refer SSL/HTTPS section given on [Docker Hub official doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/)